# How do I decode custom types from two json fields?

Tags: json, elm

I'm building an application with postgrest (backend) and elm (frontend) and right now I'm stuck writing a decoder.
I don't quite understand how to decode to my specific type instead of the base type decoders like int and string.

When I take a look at how `string` is [implemented](https://github.com/elm/json/blob/1.1.3/src/Json/Decode.elm) (line 73 to 75) it's just a call to `Elm.Kernel.Json.decodeString` which in turn is in the js base of elm.

My JSON looks something like this:

```
{ "id" : 1
, "parent_id" : 1
, "body" : "text of my body"
}
```

OR

```
{ "id" : 1
, "parent_id" : 1
, "sub_parent_id" : 2
}
```

Is it possible to decode something like that into a single record type (`Step`) which contains a custom type with multiple constructors to match the two different fields (`sub_parent_id` and `body`)
My decoder looks like this but doesn't [compile](https://gist.github.com/gimbar/0096f1881f2a7ffde633b08faf317c98):

```
import Api.Parent.Step.Types exposing ( Step, StepContent )
import Json.Decode exposing (..)
import Json.Decode.Pipeline exposing (..)

decoder : Decoder Step
decoder = 
    succeed Step
        |> required "id" int
        |> oneOf
            [ field "stepContent" stepBodyDecoder
            , field "stepContent" subStepDecoder
            ]

stepBodyDecoder : Decoder StepContent
stepBodyDecoder = 
    succeed StepContent
        |> required "body" string

subStepDecoder : Decoder StepContent
subStepDecoder =
    succeed StepContent
        |> required "sub_parent_id" decoder
```

Any my Types:

```
module Api.Parent.Step.Types exposing ( Step, StepContent )

type StepContent 
    = StepBody String
    | SubStep Step

type alias Step =
    { id : Int
    , stepContent : StepContent
    }
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: Your data model also doesn't seem to match the JSON you're trying to parse. A custom type with multiple constructors is used to model data that might have different "shapes". Either _this_ shape or _that_ shape. But the JSON you present looks to have just a single shape. Please properly describe what you're trying to do and what  specifically is hindering you. See [ask], and possibly a tutorial if you do not know the difference between a custom type with multiple constructors and a record.

Comment: Ok, I tried to improve details and my question and fixed the json example.
I'm not sure wether this is something a decoder could do.
I could parse this differently (into two fields) and do a translation of my types "later". But this wouldn't be very elegant I think.

Answer (score 1):

JSON decode pipelines expects `succeed` to be passed a function, and `StepContent` is not a function, but a type. Variant constructors are functions however, and if you look at the compiler error it suggests the right fix (although that's somewhat coincidental since it just suggest based on similar names):

```
I cannot find a `StepContent` variant:

28|     succeed StepContent
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
These names seem close though:

    StepBody
    Step
    OneOf
    SubStep
```

`StepBody` and `SubStep` are the ones you should use instead. `stepBodyDecoder` will work with just that change, and will get you at least one step further with `subStepDecoder`, but the type and decoder otherwise don't match the JSON. `sub_parent_id` is a number, not an object, so it seems like `SubStep` should take an `Int` instead of a `Step`. You can then possibly construct a separate hierarchical data structure in a subsequent step.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is written in the types (as often)

```
oneOf : List (Decoder a) -> Decoder a
```

So we have to supply a list of `Decoder StepContent`, which are the decoder functions.

And as per the relevant comment, to build a `StepContent` value, we need to form either constructor : a `StepBody` or a `SubStep`.

```
import Api.Parent.Step.Types exposing ( Step, StepContent )
import Json.Decode exposing (..)
import Json.Decode.Pipeline exposing (..)

decoder : Decoder Step
decoder = 
    succeed Step
        |> required "id" int
        |> required "stepContent"  (oneOf [ stepBodyDecoder, subStepDecoder ] )


stepBodyDecoder : Decoder StepContent
stepBodyDecoder = 
    succeed StepBody
        |> required "body" string

subStepDecoder : Decoder StepContent
subStepDecoder =
    succeed SubStep
        |> required "sub_parent_id" decoder
```